# How to display Lyrics for the song in Apple Music on iOS?

Tags: ios, shortcut, apple-music, lyrics

How to display lyrics on iOS device via Apple Music?

Answer (score 2):

1. First you have to add the lyrics to your song in iTunes (*tap on the song, then press* <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>).

[image]

2. Go to your iOS device (since it is shared via iCloud), and then single tap on cover in following screen:

[image]

3. You see the lyrics, you can switch it back to cover by single tap on the lyrics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just download musixmatch. It automatically detects song playing in Apple Music and shows lyrics with karaoke style